# A button control to display an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro in Excel, the program language is Visual Basic for Applications. I have the Developer Tab turned on, and inserted an Active X Button control to the sheet. I want it to show the text in cell B2, it contains a table header formatted as text, and the text is: "Client 1".

Here's what i have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sTxt As String
sTxt = "Cell B2 has text: "
MsgBox sTxt & Range("B2").Text
```

But the script doesn't even compile! What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you are in Design Mode, right-click the button and select **view code**:

[image]

Then paste in:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sTxt As String
    sTxt = "Cell B2 has text: "
    MsgBox sTxt & Range("B2").Text
End Sub
```

Then toggle Design Mode *off*, then click the button:

[image]